# Constructing an outer measure on a collection of subsets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be the set of three elements $\{a,b,c\}$ . On the collection of subsets $C =
\{\{ \emptyset \} , \{a\} , \{a,b\}\}$

Define the set function $m: C → [0,∞]$ by
$m( \emptyset ) = 0 $, $m(\{a,b\}) = 1$ ,$m(\{a\}) = 2$ .

i) Find an outer measure $µ*$ on $X$ such that $µ∗$ restricted to $C$ equals to $m$.

ii) Find all $µ∗$-measurable sets of X .

Comment: Shouldn't be $m(\{ a,b \}) \geq m(\{ a\})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the characteristics of an outer measure is:
$$A\subset B\Rightarrow \mu^*(A)\leq\mu^*(B)$$

If $\mu^*$ coincides with $m$ on $C$ then it cannot have that property since: $$\left\{ a\right\} \subset\left\{ a,b\right\} \wedge m\left(\left\{ a\right\} \right)=2>1=m\left(\left\{ a,b\right\} \right)$$